# Class 'Magento\Setup\Application' not found, after executing "git reset --hard"

Tags: php, git, command-line-interface, magento2

I executed `git reset --hard`, but now I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Setup\Application' not found in /home/xy/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:79
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xy/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/xy/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php on line 79
```

I executed `composer update` in hope that this fixes it, but it doesnt. How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that `git reset --hard` destroyed my `setup` folder for unknown reasons and not even `git pull` fixed it.

So I had to copy the folder from another project. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just run `git reset --hard` again and that fixed the issue.